# Understanding execution_date in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I am running an airflow DAG and wanted to understand how the execution date gets set. This is the code I am running:

`{{ execution_date.replace(day=1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}`

This always returns the first day of the month. This is the functionality that I want, but I just want to find a way to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this always returns the first of the month is that you are using a Replace to ensure the day is forced to be the 1st of the month. Simply remove ".replace(day=1)".

Comment: How can I get  first day of week means I want sunday's date

Answer (score 0):

execution_date returns a datatime object. You are using the replace method of that object to replace the “day” with the first. Then outputting that to a string with the format method.